# struts2's property tag attribute cant resolve value="(new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("").format())" at struts2 version 2.3.32

Tags: java, struts2, simpledateformat, struts-tags

i was encounter this problem when i update the Struts2 from version 2.3.15 to 2.3.32. At version 2.3.32 , `<s:property value="(new java.text.SimpleDateFormat().format())">`could not be parsed,and no error. So, how to resolve this problem?

Comment: `<s:property value="%{(new java.text.SimpleDateFormat().format())}">` ?

Comment: you have a syntax error in OGNL expression

Comment: You cannot use `new` keyword in the JSP any longer. Format date in the backend.

Comment: @Roman C  can you tell me where the wrong syntax place? please!

Comment: @Wangke (new java.text.SimpleDateFormat().format())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of writing ugly OGNL expression in property tag, that even doesn't work, why not to create a property/method in action class that does format the value.

> ### [How to format dates and numbers:](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/formatting-dates-and-numbers)
>
> A frequently asked question is how best to display dates and numbers using a specified format. There are a number of approaches for this, the most naive of which would be to add a method to your action class to do the formatting for you. This method would take in a `Date` (or subclass) object as a parameter, and return a formatted `String`.

---